# MySQL: INSERT Data if no record found in SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Can i insert data if no record found in a table in one single query ?? (If YES/NO, kindly guide)

**EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT * FROM CITIES ct WHERE ct.city = 'Any City Name';
```

if above query returns ZERO [ **0** ] records then the following query must get executed:

```
INSERT INTO CITIES (city) VALUES ('Any City Name');
SELECT * FROM CITIES ct WHERE ct.city = 'Any City Name'
```

Comment: Just place a unique index on the city column and you cannot insert the same city twice.

Comment: No, i did not mean that. I have to make a query in which the city gets added if the it is not present in database-table @Shadow

Comment: If there is a unique index on the city column, then you get a duplicate key error message. So, instead of checking if a city exists in the table, you just try to insert it and will handle the error in the application code. Checking and inserting will carry the risk that 2 users try to insert the same city at the same time and both their checks will tell them that the city does not exist yet.

Comment: Yes, i understand what your intent is. UNIQUE Constraint has already been implemented, but i don't want to fail the query as this query i want should always not give an error/exception as it will be a part of subquery. Thanx for the help/time @Shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO CITIES (city) 
SELECT 'Any City Name' 
FROM cities
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE city = 'Any City Name') LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Mr @KostasMitsarakis , CASE-1: this query does run very well if the City already exists (without entering data). But CASE-2: this query gives an error of **Duplicate entry 'NewCityName' for key 'UNQ_StrCityName' ** if the city does not already exist

Comment: Hm, i just tested it and if city already exists then zero rows will be inserted. Have you set the same value both in SELECT and WHERE of NOT EXISTS?

Comment: lolx man, I forgot to Add the LIMIT Clause , now working sooper dooper fine. By the way this question was to get idea, now this query will have to be nested in my already built Query. Thanks @KostasMitsarakis. Now Accepting your question.

Comment: Nice! I 'm glad that i helped you.